# Git submodule update from post-receive hook

Tags: git, mapping, hook, git-submodules

I'm trying to update automatically my submodule located in `var/www/php/vendor/projectX` at each commit to the `var/www` super-project. I added these lines in the `.git/hooks/post-receive` file :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Updating submodules recursively"
pwd
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

But I get this when I commit to the super-project :

```
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 346 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

remote: Updating submodules recursively
remote: /var/www/.git
remote: No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'php/vendor/projectX'
To www-data@11.22.33.44:.
3dc2404..bc46dd6  dev -> dev
```

The appropriate section is present in the .gitmodules file however, and so are the files in .git/modules. Running `git submodule update --init --recursive` manually works fine. It's only when run from the hook that it does not work. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try and :

- cd to the root folder of that repo
- specify the work-tree and git directory for that folder when doing the git command.

That would give in your post-receive hook script:

```
cd /var/www/
git --git-dir=/var/www/.git --work-tree=/var/www submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm. I spent a lot of time looking for that answer.

Comment: Why it is necessary to cd in the folder, if you provide `--work-tree`?

Comment: @Clijsters 3 and a half years  later, I am not too sure. And I would now write it `git -C /var/www submodule update --init --recursive` But maybe at the time, submodules needed to be used from the root folder only.

Comment: Yeah git told me you're right with some kind of error message. Thanks. This answer helped me out. Was just confused about it, as other git statements work out of the universe

Comment: I had the same issue, but -C didn't help. Wired.

Comment: @Lev Strange. Could you ask a separate question for me or others to have a look?

Comment: @VonC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637260/git-submodule-update-in-post-receive-hook-ignores-c