# How to hook a git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have installed a hook on the staging servers, allowing me to push to staging very easy. However, the code includes a submodule and this one does not get copied over due to access rights.

This is the post-receive hook I am using:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/staging git checkout -f
pwd
cd /home/www/staging/
git --git-dir=/home/git/staging.git --work-tree=/home/www/staging submodule update --init --recursive
```

After trying to `git push staging` I get the following:

```
remote: /home/git/staging.git
remote: Cloning into 'MEW'...
remote: Host key verification failed.
remote: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
remote: 
remote: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
remote: and the repository exists.
remote: Clone of 'git@bitbucket.org:demo/demo-mew.git' into submodule path 'MEW' failed
```

Do I need to create a cert on the staging server and add this one to bitbucket?

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535979/git-submodule-update-from-post-receive-hook

Comment: Thank you. Now it becomes more clear. Unfortunatelly I did run into another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584292/changing-url-of-git-submodule-failes Is there something I need to change to the remote repo in order to make the change?

Answer (score 0):

In the post-receive hook

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/staging git checkout -f
pwd
```

> Change dir to the root folder
>
> Specify the work tree and directory
>
> submodule update init

```
cd /home/www/
git --git-dir=<path to git dir>.git --work-tree=<path to submodule> submodule update --init --recursive
```

I hope this will help
Please let me know if this does't work
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated the question coresponding to the problem. Is the displayed config as you recommend it to be? I am running into access right problems with this.