# Changing url of Git submodule fails

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have one submodule inside a project which I would also like to push automatically to staging. Now I made apropriate changes to the hook and also changed the authentication method from password to certificate of the submodule.

Unfortunatelly git refuses to make the change of the authentication method, despite the already changed url of the origin:

```
remote: /home/git/staging.git
remote: Cloning into 'MEW'...
remote: fatal: could not read Password for 'https://myname@bitbucket.org': No such device or address
remote: Clone of 'https://myname@bitbucket.org/demo/demo-mew.git' into submodule path 'MEW' failed

node1:/home/www/demo/MEW$ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:demo/demo-mew.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:demo/demo-mew.gitdemo)
```

cat .git/config

```
...
[submodule "MEW"]
     url = git@bitbucket.org:demo/demo-mew.git
...
```

Is this a bug or do I need to change something else to make the change happen? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: can you show your .gitmodules file ?

Comment: I just checked. In deed there was the old pw syntax, I changed it now to ssh. However I do get the same warnings: Host key verification failed.
remote: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
remote: 
remote: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
remote: and the repository exists.

Comment: Can you clone the submodule in other dir ?

Comment: Yes, on the machine where I am trying to do a git push staging, I can do a git clone submodulename

Comment: maybe you can grep for https: //myname@bitbucket.org in the .git directory and check if there is any config file we don't know about ?

Comment: Yes there are entries in the modname/logs/ directory. Nothing besides that.

Comment: Just in case, have you tried git submodule deinit and git submodule add again?