# git submodule update in post-receive hook ignores -C

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-post-receive

I try to write a post-receive hook to build a static webpage, but the git submodule update --init command fails. The script runs successfully when not run by the hook.

```
OUTPUT=$HOME/post_receive_out

REPO=$HOME/repositories/personal/www_root.git
WORKING_DIR=$HOME/hugo_web_temp
WWW_DIR=/var/www/servers/levente.logonex.eu/pages

echo -ne "This is the post receive hook. I am " > $OUTPUT

whoami >> $OUTPUT

rm -rf $WORKING_DIR
git clone $REPO $WORKING_DIR
git -C $WORKING_DIR submodule update --init

hugo -s $WORKING_DIR/lev -d $WWW_DIR
chmod -R a+r $WWW_DIR
```

says:

fatal: not a git repository: '.'

For now I fixed it with this:

```
cd  $WORKING_DIR
git --git-dir $WORKING_DIR/.git --work-tree $WORKING_DIR submodule update --init
```

found in [Git submodule update from post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535979/git-submodule-update-from-post-receive-hook/21546191)

Comment: What version of Git are you using on that server?

Comment: @VonC, I'm using git version 2.20.1 from Debian stable.

Comment: OK so above the 1.8.5 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115526/6309) required to use -C